# Dynamically create column by Aggregating other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a new column called "Premium" by summing the values of the column "PremiumByCode" based on their respective "Codes" column.. I want to display only the non-zero Premium rows in the final result ..Also, I am trying to approximate the final Premium column with no decimal values .  I am using MS SQL and here is my below code.

I want to create new column as following :

`[Premium] = max([PremiumByCodes])` per Codes and finally show only the records that has non-zero [Premium] value

```
   ...............
    select  a.FileID,
                a.InsName, 
                a.[Policy Number],
                a.[Effective Date], 
                a.LOB, 
                b.Codes, 
                --a.[NWP],              
                [PremiumByCodes]  = a.[NWP]/(1-c.[Commission%]-c.[Deduction%]),
                c.[Commission%]*100 as Commission,
                c.[Deduction%]*100 as Deduction,  
                c.[Currency]


                --Codes_Commission = [Premium] * c.[Commission%]
        from #temp1 a
        inner join IT.dbo.Perils_Codes_Lookup b 
        on b.Peril = a.LOB

        right join (
        -- Extract Commission Information
            select FileID, 
                    --ISNULL([Commission], 0) as Commisssion,
                    CAST (ISNULL([Commission], 0) as float) as [Commission%],           
                    CAST (ISNULL([Deduction], 0) as float) as [Deduction%],
                    ISNULL([Currency],0) as [Currency]
        from (select FileID, Worksheet, Label,LOB,Data
        from IT.[dbo].[DATA] 
        where 
        FileID = 18265
        and Worksheet in ('Summary')
        and LOB in ( 'N/A')
        ) d 
        PIVOT
            (max([Data]) 
             for [Label] in ([Commission], [Deduction],[Currency])
             --,[Commission])
            )piv 
        )c

        on c.FileID = a.FileID
```

My current table looks like:

```
+ ----- + ---------------- +
| Codes | PremiumByASL     |
+ ----- + ---------------- +
| 010   | 27857.9403619788 |
| 027   | 4295.89527248191 |
| 021   | 22211.0617400998 |
| 120   | 3718.53861388411 |
| 012   | 0                |
| 120   | 6952.564745595   |
| 025   | 23970.5245355982 |
| 021   | 0                |
| 021   | 63683.0552706094 |
| 021   | 139.161555555556 |
| 021   | 39.3638524365101 |
+ ----- + ---------------- +
```

My expected output is like below :

```
+ ----- + ---------------- +
| Codes | Premium          |
+ ----- + ---------------- +
| 010   | 27,858           |
| 021   | 86,073           |
| 027   | 4,296            |
| 120   | 249,803          |
| 025   | 23,971           |
+ ----- + ---------------- +
```

Comment: can you also add expected output

Comment: Hi TheGameiswar , I have added the expected output as well. Thanks

Comment: Do you expect us to read all that code? Simplify/minimize the problem!

Comment: Why is Code 012 eliminated in the output? Aside from that this is really basic aggregation using SUM and a group by.

Comment: Seam Lange, I want to eliminate the non zero ones. I am not sure how to create new column [Premium] with dynamically created column [PremiumByCodes]

Comment: @user7394916 Could you please clarify if you want the sum or the max of Premium by Code. You start by saying sum, but in your first code block you wrote max, so it is a little bit unclear. **Also**, it's not clear how your query relates to the tables. For example, your query selects 10 fields, but your Current Table only has two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a view, function or another temporary table that simply returns a set with each code and its aggregated premiums. Then join with that view, function or temporary table.

That way you can perform whatever follow-up logic on the results. And you can filter out the codes that return zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Cost the field as money**

```
 CONVERT(varchar, CAST(Premium AS money), 1)
```